# Securing a JSF application to prevent access to application's XML resources inside WEB-INF folder

Tags: security, jsf, web.xml

I am currently supporting a J2EE Web Application that uses JSF 1.2 with Spring MVC. Recently it was observed that the application is allowing to display various XML resources under the WEB-INF/ folder by tweaking the URL. For example, the URL to the application is https://www.example.org/abc-app/faces//WEB-INF/web.xml cause web.xml to be displayed (abc_app is context root; and there is deliberate two '//' in the URL which causes the xml files to display). The application did not have  element defined in web.xml, so I added it as follows:

```
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>excluded</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>No Access</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/abc-app/WEB-INF/*.xml</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/abc-app/faces//WEB-INF/*.xml</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/abc-app/faces/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/faces//*</url-pattern>
            <url-pattern>/*.xml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>NoAccess</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>   
</security-constraint>
```

Unfortunately this has not helped and the application still displays the XML files. Any advice on what can be done to prevent display of XML files under the WEB-INF folder?

Some additional information: 
Our application is deployed on WebSphere Application Server and does it's own authentication using SAML at the WebServer level.

Comment: Best thing to do is upgrade JSF. And what about `<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*.xml</url-pattern>`

Comment: @Kukeltje - I have tried `<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/*.xml</url-pattern>` and it did not help either. Upgrade from jsf 1.2 to 2.0 is considered as major change, It would be very helpful if there is anything else that can be tried. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but spending time on searching for solutions on 10 year old technology when it is too much effort to upgrade and with all (other) security issues in that stack is not where I'd like to spend my time on. Please don't take it personal, just my point of view. Btw, this might just be an ancient bug...

Comment: Understand. Thanks for taking time to provide your input. I was only trying to see if there was something else that could solve the problem without needing to upgrade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed web.xml and noticed that it had the following Servlet mappings:

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I updated it to only have the following

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This helped solving the issues and the XML files are not longer accessible.

However, it is strongly recommended to update JSFv1 to JSF2 in case someone is still using it.